# Tape Gradient with respect to multiple variables

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a model in eager mode of tensorflow, and I need to calculate gradient with respect to multiple variables, say w1 and w2 , which have different shapes.

I know that using the persistent mode of tf.GradientTape(), I can take the gradient with respect to the variables in turn. However, I want to concatenate the variables and do it all at once:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
     # build a function of variables w1, w2
     loss = f(w1, w2)
grad = tape.gradient(loss, [w1,w2])
```

Off course, the above code raises an error for [w1, w2], as their shapes are not compatible.

I am wondering how should I concatenate the variables with different size, so that it works for subsequent applying the gradients?

Comment: Huh? That code should work. Can you provide a specific minimal example where this fails?

Comment: I am trying with w1 and w2 as trainable variables of two different MLPs and it fails!

Comment: What I mean is, you should provide full, runnable code that reproduces the problem, as well as the _full_ error trace. As it is, we cannot help you because the snippet you posted is not informative. The problem might not even be related to `GradientTape`.

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer for this question?

Answer (score -1):

To calculate gradients with respect to multiple variables in TensorFlow 2, especially when these variables have different shapes, you don't need to concatenate them. TensorFlow's `tf.GradientTape()` can handle lists of variables and compute gradients for each variable separately, even when they have different shapes.

The `tf.GradientTape()` keeps track of operations for automatic differentiation. When you pass a list of variables to the `tape.gradient()` method, TensorFlow calculates the gradient of the loss with respect to each of the variables in the list, without the need for concatenating them.

Here's a minimal example to illustrate this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the model variables
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([3, 2]), name='w1')
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([2, 1]), name='w2')

# Define a simple loss function
def f(w1, w2):
    return tf.reduce_sum(w1 ** 2) + tf.reduce_sum(w2 ** 3)

# Using GradientTape for automatic differentiation
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = f(w1, w2)

# Compute gradients with respect to each variable
grads = tape.gradient(loss, [w1, w2])

# grads is a list of tensors corresponding to the gradients of the loss
# with respect to each of w1 and w2, regardless of their shape
print("Gradient w.r.t w1:", grads[0])
print("Gradient w.r.t w2:", grads[1])
```

In this example, `grads` will be a list containing the gradients of `loss` with respect to `w1` and `w2`, computed separately. There is no need to concatenate `w1` and `w2` because TensorFlow's gradient computation is capable of handling lists of tensors with differing shapes.

The same goes with the training of two different models:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def train_step(model1, model2, X, loss_fn, optimizer):
    """
    Perform a training step for two models.

    Args:
    model1 (tf.keras.Model): First model to be trained.
    model2 (tf.keras.Model): Second model to be trained.
    X (Tensor): Input data.
    loss_fn (function): A function to compute the loss.
    optimizer (tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer): Optimizer to apply gradients.

    Returns:
    Tensor: The computed loss.
    """
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass for both models
        output1 = model1(X)
        output2 = model2(X)

        # Compute the loss
        loss = loss_fn(output1, output2)

    # Get trainable variables from both models
    trainable_variables = model1.trainable_variables + model2.trainable_variables

    # Compute gradients
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)

    # Update the weights
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

    return loss
```